# SPARQL queries for data-vocabulary.org

Tags: sparql, schema.org, vocabulary

I am using SPARQL queries to query the data that is marked up using the Schema.org vocabulary. I see that some sites are still using Data-Vocabulary.org for their mark up.

Can I just replace the `schema.org` with `data-vocabulary.org` in my SPARQL queries to make the queries work?

Is it only a namespace difference between Schema.org and Data-Vocabulary.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your queries. If you want to see all triples, it’s sufficient to replace the namespace. But if you query for certain types/properties, it might not be sufficient.

Data-Vocabulary.org and Schema.org are similar vocabularies which often use the same names for types/properties, but not always.

Examples:

- [`Breadcrumb`](http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#Breadcrumb) vs. [`BreadcrumbList`](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)
- [`Address`](http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#Address) vs. [`PostalAddress`](http://schema.org/PostalAddress)
- [Data-Vocabulary.org’s `image` property](http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#image) can only be used for products, while [Schema.org’s `image` property](http://schema.org/image) can be used for everything.
- …

Comment: often , but not always :)

Comment: is there a way in SPARQL to use the same alias for different namespaces ,i.e. an s for schema.org as well as data-vocabulary.org ? my probelm is that the page is being marked up with properties from both the vocabularies.

Comment: @user1965449: Sounds like a separate question you could ask here on Stack Overflow. Keep in mind that the meaning of the types/properties doesn’t have to be the same just because they have the same name (i.e., a Schema.org property "foo" could mean something totally different than a Data-Vocabulary.org property of the same name; I don’t know any example, but then again I don’t know Data-Vocabulary.org very well).

Comment: @user1965449 You can't do exactly what you're asking, but you could do, e.g.: `prefix s1: <...> prefix s2: <...> select * where { values ?foo { s1:foo s2:foo } ?subject ?foo ?object }`.

Comment: great idea ! so the values ?foo {s1:foo s2:foo} acts like s1 or s2? Thanks.